# Can't display field of referenced mongo document in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am working on a To-Do application to get some practice with Rails3 and MongoDB.

I have an Item which was a tag and a tag will have many items associated with it.

My Issue:  The show.html.erb does not want to display the tag name.

```
# models/item.rb
class Item
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name
 field :completed, :type => Boolean
 referenced_in :tag  
end

# models/tag.rb
class Tag
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name
 key :name
 references_many :items
end

# items_controller.rb
 def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
         format.html # show.html.erb
         format.xml  { render :xml => @item }
    end
 end

<!-- items/show.html.erb -->
<p>Name: <%= @item.name %></p>
<p>Completed: <%= @item.completed %></p>
<p>Tag: <%= @item.tag.name %></p>
```

The third or tag line of the show file is what is giving my problems.  The error is below:

> Document not found for class Tag with
>   id(s) 4cd75765f5c4932f19000002.

if I replace the line in question with the line below then the correct tag id is displayed (however I want the tag name obviously)

```
<p>Tag: <%= @item.tag_id %></p>
```

Comment: What do you get from `@item.tag` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tag class has two attributes named 'name'. 
Try removing `key :name`

Comment: you were correct but i think for the wrong reason.  removing the key worked.  think it worked because the key attribute is used so the name is used to identify the tag in the address.  so it was looking for the tag name using the tag id.

Comment: After using key a bit, I've realised you answered your own question better. The tag you were referencing had already been written to the database using ObjectId as key. I'm sure you've since discovered that once you wrote new records to the database with 'key :name',  you got your expected outcome.